# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on local IIS site when trying to hit API

Tags: vue.js, iis, .net-core, routes, windows-server-2019

I have an application with a VueJS frontend and .netcore backend. I am trying to deploy the site to an Azure VM 2019 windows server.

I used this guide to setup the website on IIS:
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/01/11/vuejs-aspnet-core-on-azure-with-sql-server-how-to-deploy-a-full-stack-app-to-microsoft-azure

The following web.config is probably the most relevant from that guide

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Vue" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/api/.*" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My endpoints look like this: `[HttpGet("/api/player/all")]`

I have a Main.js in my Vue side that sets up axios to use port 44371

```
const axiosConfig = {
  baseURL: 'https://localhost:44371',
};
Vue.prototype.$axios = axios.create(axiosConfig)
```

And finally my launchsettings

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:60000",
      "sslPort": 44371
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Service": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:60000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So far I haven't been able to get a good error message, everything works fine when trying this on my local machine. I feel like I have some port or path incorrectly configured. Thanks.

Comment: Are both VueJS and .netcore deployed on the same IIS? I suggest you use FRT to troubleshoot this issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis